# DB2 Setting up table access based on LDAP groups

Tags: db2, authentication

I have a DB2 database installed and set up. My users can access any table that I grant SELECT to the PUBLIC group. However, it doesn't appear to acknowledge the groups the user is in in LDAP. The user belongs to the groups Development and ITDev. I have added both those groups to a table with SELECT permissions, but the user gets a message that their id does not have select access to that table. What do I need to change?

Comment: Have you configured DB2 to access LDAP?  You can do this via an LDAP security plugin or via transparent LDAP...

Comment: And even if you are using groups....I would highly recommend you go with roles rather than explicitly permission against objects. Going to save you a lot of pain later as you can move groups around within roles, etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the database is set up to use LDAP, as that is how users are logging in, but it doesn't seem to recognize the group. (I am using groups here because as we are developing the application, members of the Programmers group need extra permissions to modify tables, that won't exist after the development process concludes)